# Purpose of ipv4.dns-option in nmcli

Tags: dns, networkmanager, dnsmasq, nmcli, dynamic-dns

`dns-options` can be changed for connection name `myname` to the value `value` using

```
 nmcli con modify myname ipv4.dns-options value
```

Using interactive mode, I get a short description of what `dns-options` does.

```
nmcli> describe ipv4.dns-options

=== [dns-options] ===
[NM property description]
Array of DNS options. NULL means that the options are unset and left at the default. In this case NetworkManager will use default options. This is distinct from an empty list of properties.
```

**Question**: What are the value of `dns-options` field and what is the purpose of `dns-option`?

Answer (score 3):

From some digging around in the NetworkManager source tree (`libnm-core/nm-setting-ip-config.c` and look for `NDOTS`) and knowledge of [`resolv.conf(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolv.conf.5.html), the options appear to be the same options that can be set in `/etc/resolv.conf`, such as

```
-bash-4.2$ grep options /etc/resolv.conf 
options rotate
options timeout:1
options attempts:3
```

Answer (score 1):

I would upvote @thrig answer but I don't have enough reputation yet.
I recently had to configure DNS rotate and timeout. I found out that you have to list them in a single command using quotes:

```
nmcli con modify <interface_name> ipv4.dns-options "timeout:1 rotate"
```

This shows up in `/etc/resolv.conf` like so:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
options timeout:1 rotate
```